# expanding a dynamic array in C and getting nothing back

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

C noob here. I had some code working fine when it was all in `main()` but when I started factoring it out it died. I know this is simple, that I'm missing some key element and I'll only have to be shown this once (I promise!). So here goes:

in types.h:

```
typedef struct {
  char *orig_str; // various ints snipped for clarity
} Card;

typedef struct {
  size_t num_cards;
  Card *cards;  // same here
} Deck;
```

in main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Deck deck;
  // clipped the part opening input_fp, it's working fine
  read_deck(&deck, input_fp);
  for(int i = 0; i < deck.num_cards; i++) {
    fprintf("%s", deck.cards[i].orig_str);
  }
}
```

in input.c, where I moved the code formerly in `main`:

```
void read_deck(Deck *deck, FILE *pfile) {
  Card *card = NULL;
  char line_buf[MAX_LINE_LEN];
  int line_len;

  while(TRUE) {
    if(read_line(line_buf, input_fp) == EOF) break;
    line_len = strlen(line_buf);

    /* make a new card and copy in the text */
    card = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
    card->orig_str = calloc(1, line_len * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(card->orig_str, line_buf);

    /* calloc/realloc the deck and add this card to it */
    if(deck->num_cards == 0) {
      deck->num_cards++;
      deck->cards = calloc(1, sizeof(Card *));
    } else {
      deck->num_cards++;
      deck->cards = realloc(deck->cards, deck->num_cards*sizeof(Card *));
    }
    deck->cards[deck->num_cards - 1] = *card;
  }
}
```

When I trace through in gdb inside `read_deck`, everything seems fine, I can:

```
 p deck->cards[0].orig_str = "CM TESTEX5"
 p deck->cards[1].orig_str = "CM YAGI TEST"
 p deck->cards[2].orig_str = "CM 78 SEGMENTS. SIGMA"
```

But when the loop completes and it returns to `main`, most cards other than [0] no longer have values:

```
p deck->cards[0].orig_str = "CM TESTEX5"
p deck->cards[1].orig_str = ""
p deck->cards[2].orig_str = ""
```

Digging a bit deeper, I can see bits of valid data showing up from very different cards - card 24 orig_str looks OK, but the data it has is from card 30! The next time I ran it, that data was in card 20.

I assume the problem is that I'm mallocing something the wrong size so the array or string pointers are wrong. But why would that only happen at the end of the method?

Ok, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I beats me why you have a struct which has a pointer to another struct that only contains a pointer. Keep it simple.

Comment: As I noted in the comment, the struct has a bunch of ints as well, I removed them so that this didn't flow off the page.

Comment: `deck->cards` is an array of `Cards` not an array of `Card *`, so your allocation is incorrect.  `calloc(1, sizeof(Card *));` only allocates space for a pointer-to-card but you want space for a `Card` object. Change to `sizeof(Card)`. Same with `realloc`.

Comment: `calloc(1, line_len * sizeof(char));` you need to use `line_len+1` to allow space for the null terminator.

Comment: There's also no reason to use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, since you're going to overwrite it immediately.

Comment: But if you use `calloc()`, write it as `calloc(line_len+1, sizeof(char))`. One of the benefits of `calloc()` is that it does the multiplication for you.

Comment: On the other hand, since you alloc a new `Card` anyway, maybe `deck->cards` should `Card**`.

Comment: Johnny, that was it, obviously in retrospect. If you make that an answer I'll upvote it. It points to my lack of true understanding of the arrays, I though arrays WERE lists of pointers, but of course that is not the case. Barmar, I was told to ALWAYS use calloc for the simple reason that if you malloc, one day you'll forget to zero.

Comment: And Johnny, can you expand on that last comment a bit?

Answer (score 1):

`deck->cards` is an array of `Cards` not an array of `Card *`, so your allocation is incorrect.

```
calloc(1, sizeof(Card *));
```

only allocates space for a pointer-to-card but you want space for a `Card` object. Change to

```
calloc(1, sizeof(Card));.
```

Same with `realloc`

However, since you are already allocate the `Card` on the heap

```
card = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
```

You could change the type of the array to `Card **` and just store those pointers in the array

```
deck->cards[deck->num_cards - 1] = card;
```

But I don't think you want to do that, so you can probably disregard that.

You don't need to allocate the temp `Card` on the heap. You could just change the local variable to:

```
Card card;
```

and eliminate `card = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));` altogether. As it is you have a memory leak because you never `free` them but this way you don't need to worry about that.

Last note, `deck->cards[deck->num_cards - 1] = *card;` does a shallow copy. Which may or may not be an issue. Can't say for sure with the simplified code.

Updated function:

```
void read_deck(Deck *deck, FILE *pfile) {
  Card card;   // No longer a pointer
  char line_buf[MAX_LINE_LEN];
  int line_len;

  while(TRUE) {
    if(read_line(line_buf, input_fp) == EOF) break;
    line_len = strlen(line_buf);

    /* make a new card and copy in the text */
    // You weren't allocating space for the '\0' so +1 added
    card.orig_str = calloc(1, (line_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(card->orig_str, line_buf);

    /* calloc/realloc the deck and add this card to it */
    if(deck->num_cards == 0) {
      deck->num_cards++;
      deck->cards = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
    } else {
      deck->num_cards++;
      deck->cards = realloc(deck->cards, deck->num_cards*sizeof(Card));
    }
    // Shallow copy temp object to array
    deck->cards[deck->num_cards - 1] = card;
  }
}
```

I should also mention, calling `realloc` with a `NULL` pointer is the same as calling `malloc` so you could simplify even further by having only 1 allocation.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is not needed. `calloc` is fine and so is the way you implement it. How large is `Card` initialized to be?

```
card = calloc(1, sizeof(Card));
```

If there is no specific value then it could cutting off data with each iteration, which is why just tracing through it works and everything is visible but not when you call the `fprintf` function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following lines have a logic error:

```
if(deck->num_cards == 0) {
  deck->num_cards++;
  deck->cards = calloc(1, sizeof(Card *));
} else {
  deck->num_cards++;
  deck->cards = realloc(deck->cards, deck->num_cards*sizeof(Card *));
}
```

Most likely you meant to write `calloc(1, sizeof(Card))` and similarly for the `realloc`. If `sizeof(Card *) == sizeof(Card)` you probably wouldn't notice any issue, which is indeed the case with your snipped example since `Card` only contains a pointer member.